# "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined" when migrating to Parcel 2

Tags: node.js, cloudinary, parceljs

I'm trying to migrate a Node.js webapp from Parcel 1 to Parcel 2.

I have a function in the client-side javascript code (that Parcel bundles) that calls another function I'm importing from a utility functions file in the back-end Node.js code.

All other front-end functions work and all other Node.js functions which require Node.js process still work.
When I trigger calling this function in the code:

```
getCloudinaryUrl.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

Everything worked just fine in Parcel 1, so I'm assuming this is a problem with my Parcel 2 configuration, not with Cloudinary.

The offending lines:

In getColudinaryUrl.js (back-end):

```
const { Cloudinary } = require('cloudinary-core');
...
// this is what triggers the error
const cloudName = process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME;
const cl = new Cloudinary({
  cloud_name: cloudName,
});
```

In index.js (front-end):

```
import getCloudinaryUrl from './../../utils/getCloudinaryUrl';
// then I'm calling it later on in the code
```

In server.js (back-end)
This is the only place in the code where I do dotenv.config:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
...
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });
```

My OLD package.json with Parcel 1 which worked:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --public-url /js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
    "build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --public-url /js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "parcel-bundler": "1.12.3",
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14"
  }
```

My NEW package.json file which doesn't work:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "watch:js": "rm -rf .parcel-cache/ && parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --public-url /js --dist-dir ./public/js",
    "build:js": "rm -rf .parcel-cache/ && parcel build ./public/js/index.js --public-url /js --dist-dir ./public/js"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-nightly.524",
    ...
  },
"engines": {
    "node": "^14"
  },
"default": "./public/js/bundle.js",
"targets": { 
    "main": false,
    "default": {
      "includeNodeModules": true,

      "scopeHoist": false
    }

  }
```

I added `rm -rf .parcel-cache/ &&` since otherwise a second build would always fail.

I read the migration guide and several other pages:

- https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/
- https://v2.parceljs.org/features/module-resolution/
- https://v2.parceljs.org/features/node-emulation/

It wasn't easy for me to read and, being rather new, Parcel 2 doesn't have many resources online to read over. That's how I ended up with the new package.json file above which gave me the least amount of errors (excluding the one above).

If there's anything else I should add to the question, I will gladly provide it.

How do I configure Parcel 2 to detect process in that one file?

Answer (score 0):

It could be as easy as adding `CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME=something` to a `.env` file in the project root?

Comment: I've already done that as it worked before using Parcel v1. Thanks, though. Does anyone know where I can get more help with this?

Comment: This seems to be a rhetorical question. It would be helpful if you could phrase the Answer to be more assertive. Please visit [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for anyone ending up here, I eventually fixed it by removing the `engines` key from the `package.json`.